# How can I have an aggregate function in the WHERE clause?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, count, sum

Using PostgreSQL 9.3.24

**Issue**

Just simple operation, but I don't know how to do that best simplest way.

How can I display results only when sum of `available_count`s for same `product_id` is `0` and `onway` is `0` or `NULL`? I.e. `130479` in this case. I want display all values, for every `store_id`.

Thank you.

**Update**

I tried aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE.

```
select
*

from
j_product_store_availability psa 

where
sum(available_count) = '0'
and onway = '0'

group by
product_id

order by
product_id
```

Input.

```
product_id | store_id | available count | onway 
1          | 1        | 0               | 0
1          | 2        | 0               | 0
1          | 3        | 0               | 0
2          | 1        | 0               | 0
2          | 2        | 0               | 0
2          | 3        | 0               | 0
3          | 1        | 0               | 0
3          | 2        | 0               | 0
3          | 3        | 1               | 0
4          | 1        | 0               | 0
4          | 2        | 0               | 0
4          | 3        | 0               | 1
```

Expected output.

```
product_id | store_id | available count | onway 
1          | 1        | 0               | 0
1          | 2        | 0               | 0
1          | 3        | 0               | 0
2          | 1        | 0               | 0
2          | 2        | 0               | 0
2          | 3        | 0               | 0
```

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe See updated question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT product_id
              FROM j_product_store_availability
              GROUP BY product_id
              HAVING 0 = SUM(available_count)
                 AND 0 = SUM(onway) )
SELECT t.*
FROM j_product_store_availability t
JOIN cte ON t.product_id = cte.product_id
```

Of course the solution is correct only in the case when both available_count and onway cannot be negative.

If not then use

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT product_id
              FROM j_product_store_availability
              GROUP BY product_id
              HAVING 0 = COUNT(NULLIF(available_count, 0))
                 AND 0 = COUNT(NULLIF(onway, 0)) )
SELECT t.*
FROM j_product_store_availability t
JOIN cte ON t.product_id = cte.product_id
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=cc4fe97ea1a054c4044568c68417f617)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a window function, which does something similar to a `GROUP BY`, but outpots all rows and not just the groups.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *,
             sum(available_count) OVER (PARTITION BY product_id) AS sum_count
      FROM j_product_store_availability psa) AS subq
WHERE onway = 0
  AND sum_count = 0
ORDER BY product_id;
```

Comment: @LarenzAlbe Thanks, but it shows me `product_id` where sum of all `available_count` (sum of `available_count ` of all `store_id` for one `product_id`) is not `0`.

Comment: Condition is: `display every row of available_count of every store_id (1-10) when sum of all available_counts of store_id is 0 and onway is 0`.

Comment: Updated my question. Thank you.

Comment: I think I understand the problem now. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you! It is exactly what I want.

Comment: @genderbee Are you sure? See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=bb1e88d03c9cd58e2f68333de8313b73) - there is 2 excess rows above your expected output...

Comment: @Akina You are right, seems it is not exactly I want.